# How were the ions produced in Lawrence's 1932 cyclotron?

Tags: particle-physics, radioactivity

From what I understand Lawrence split the atom shortly after Cockcroft and Walton. The ions were 1.25Mev protons originating at the center of the cyclotron. A rather small circular device. I looked at the Schematics but does not show exactly how he did it.

Although a different question is this essentially what Glen Seaborg used to bombard Neptunium in order to produce plutonium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in the original article in [Physics Review](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.40.19) in the Experimental Arrangement section (starting on page 25).

> The source of ions. An ideal source of ions is one that delivers to the
> diametral region between the electrodes large quantities of ions with low
> components of velocity normal to the plane of the accelerators. This requirement
> has most conveniently been met in the present experiments merely by
> having a filament placed above the diametral region from which a stream of
> electrons pass down along the magnetic lines of force, generating ions of
> gases in the tube.

It is shown in Figures 1 and 2 in the paper. Basically a hot filament producing electrons to ionize the gas.

Your second question is answered in another [Physical Review](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.70.555https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.70.555) article. Uranyl nitrate in a paraffin block was placed behind a beryllium target irradiated with deuterons. The nuclear reaction between Be and D produced neutrons.